# xCode 8: How to make UILabel font auto resize/scale for different devices in storyboard without writing code

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode8

I've been trying to fix auto resizing/scaling of font in UIlabel in storyboard but no success. Already wasted two days.

I've searched and tried all the possible solutions but none worked for me.

I've a line of long text which I want to fit in the width of various devices in the storyboard itself without writing any line of code in swift file.

I've followings right now
1) Leading and trailing space
2) Fixed height 
3) Large font size so that it fits largest size devices.
4) Lines = 0
5) Autoshrink->Minimum font scale = 0.5
6) I've tried changing content hugging priority but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me in getting this fixed?

Tx

Comment: Size classes are not perfect. With size classes you have to choose a font size which will fit let's say all iPhones and another font size which will fit for iPads. This doesn't auto fit/scale/resize font to fit width. Classes are workaround but not a solution. I'm looking for auto scaling/resizing solution where I don't have to use classes but achieve the same with constraints like we do for images.

Comment: You don't want write code, only way use size class to change UIlabel font size.

Comment: Size classes are perfect for what you want to do